# Taking a value from an array and storing it into a variable for a SQL search

Tags: php, html, sql

Perhaps there may be an easier way to do this however, I need the project to select a patient from the drop down menu. Then when the dropdown menu has got a value, the text field needs to take the NHS number from that drop down menu (array) so that it can be posted elsewhere.

```
            <select name="patient" class="textbox" required>
            <option value="">Select a patient</option>                    
            <?php
            include 'dbconnection.php';

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM clients ORDER by firstname ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $result = $conn-> query($sql); 
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row["firstname"]." ".$row["lastname"]; ?>">

                <?php echo $row["firstname"]." ".$row["lastname"] .", ".$row["addressl1"].", ".$row["addressl2"].", ".$row["county"].", ".$row["postcode"].", ".$row["nhsnum"]; ?></option>
                <?php

                $nhs = $row['nhsnum'];
            }                                       
            ?>
            </select> 

             <?php

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE nhsnum = $nhs ";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $result = $conn-> query($sql); 
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
            ?>
                <input type="text" placeholder="NHS number" readonly value=" <?php echo $row["nhsnum"]; ?>"> 


                <?php

            }                                       
            ?>
```

As you may see, I have created dummy variables of $nhs however its a static variable and doesnt change upon user selection from the drop down list. Can anyone explain how I can merge the two together.

[DB setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK5cL.png)

Comment: You need to use javascript on client's action, please read more on javascript - ajax technique. This could be done by `onChange` method when the user selects an option from your dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should declare the $nhs outside the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX, as already suggested, or a form submit button. Your second query should be where your AJAX or submitted form goes. Use $_GET or $_POST, if you are using get or post method, to intercept the option value.  Assign that value to your $nhs, then use as you have.

Set the option value to the $nhs value you want, not the person’s name. Example using $_POST

```
if(isset($_POST['patient'])){
    $nhs=$_POST['patient'];
}else{
    // whatever code you want to handle a non-submitted value.
}
```

Add additional code to prevent SQL injection.